# Python library to create leaflet with graphics formatted text and tables

Tags: python

I am using python to analyse stack of data and produce some analytics based on it in form of charts, tables, formatted text. Can someone suggest a python library that will help me to put these results on some form of canvas in a nice and formatted order that i can save as jpg or pdf and use it later in word or ppt documents?

Comment: Could you please post what have you tried so far and please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. As a new member to Stack Overflow, you probably want to read the [tour] and browse the [Help].

Comment: Code is irrelevant here. I have pandas dataframe and functions that return me a bunch of results in form of matplotlib charts, series and dataframes which i want to put in a nicely formatted manner on a single pre defined canvas, which i can then save as picture or pdf or html file for sharing. I am trying to automate preparation of part of analytical report. My initial thought was to use tkinter library, but maybe there are some more elegant solutions.

Comment: [The house rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are not "irrelevant", though, and they read "no library recommendations". As a new member you could have at least read the introductory [tour] as it outlines the main rules, and you may want to browse the [Help] as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ever in need of python libraries, [this](https://pypi.org/) link will be of help.

For visualization, you would need [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html#introductory) which produces all sorts of plots: line plots, bar graphs, etc.

[ggplot](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/) is another one you can look into which is based on R's ggplot2 library and is quite good.

Comment: I found ReportLab. Will inform how it fits my purposes.